# question on probability of roll of one dice

Tags: probability

this is the scenario.

roll one dice 6 times and note the result of each roll.  lets say the results are the following. 3, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4.   this will become the standard sequence.

begin to roll the dice again.  As soon as the next 3 is rolled, then what is the probability that the next 5 rolls will be exactly has follows.  3, 6, 2,  1, 4 ?
The remainder of the standard sequence.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  the probability of any specified sequence of five die rolls is the same.

Comment: thank you but i dont know  enough about probability.

Comment: as soon as the next $3$ face up in a roll then the probability to get the sequence $3-6-2-1-4$ exactly after is $\frac1{6^5}$, assuming that the dice is fair, that is, that each value of the dice have the same probability to face up when you roll it.

Comment: Thank you very much masacroso!